# How >>> operator works in Java

Tags: java, binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm understanding how `>>>` works. To do it I have this program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        short i = 130;
        byte b = (byte)i;
        String a = Integer.toBinaryString(256 + (int) b);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        System.out.println(a.substring(a.length() -8));
        System.out.println(b);

        byte c = (byte) (b >>> 2);
        String x = Integer.toBinaryString(256 + (int) c);

        System.out.println(x.substring(x.length() -8));
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

And I get this output:

```
10000010
10000010
-126
11100000
-32
```

To show as binary, I found [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2089318) how to show a byte as a binary string.

Operator `>>>` will add zeros, but I get this:

```
-126
11100000
-63
```

Instead of:

```
-126
10100000
-32
```

It is adding a 1 instead of 0:

```
11100000
10100000
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I don't understand anything.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo wrong.  Also I feel like this question has been answered before

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo `>>>` is a zero-fill right-shift.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `b >>> 2` is first promoting `b` to an int with value -126, i.e.

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000010
```

When you shift that right by 2 with zero-extension, you get:

```
00111111 11111111 11111111 11100000
```

When that's then converted back to a byte, it just lops off the first three words, giving 11100000, which is what you're seeing.

See [section 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) of the JLS for more details about bit-shifting.

Comment: I was about to link your answer from another post you did on this about C# equivalent

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is another to represent a byte as a binary string? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VansFannel: I don't know of one offhand, although I'd probably use: `Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xff)`.